# Custom Objects not Showing in Data Cloud

Tags: custom-object, permission-sets, datacloud, salesforce-cdp, data-streams

I can't see my custom object in my Data Cloud Demo Org, and someone has answered that we need to assign the permission set to the user named "Data Cloud salesforce Connector" to view the Custom object. But I can't even get that permission set also. Has anyone experienced like this before?

[image: The Image of my permission set that the user assigned to]